# List iteration to new list Python

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.7

I have a list of the following format. Example below is a subset of the list:

```
[('227', 1, 227), ('233', 1, 233), ('297', 1, 297), ('298', 3, 298), ('316', 1, 316), ('240', 1, 240), ('255', 1, 91), ('255', 92, 184)]
```

Where `item[0]` is the ID, `item[1]` is the start and `item[2]` is the stop. `item[0]` is actually a long string of numbers and letters, I just simplified it but it is a string not an int.

I want to iterate through the list find a unique ID with the lowest start and highest stop value.

If have a problem with only adding one ID

```
for item in List:
    ID = item[0]
    Start = item[1]
    Stop = item[2]
    List2 = []
    if item not in List2:
        List2.extend(item)
    elif item in List2:
        continue
    print List2
```

The new list only has the last item in it. How do I fix this.

Comment: You recreate the `List2` list each loop iteration. It's not clear to me what you mean by *unique ID with the lowest start and highest stop value* here, can you tell us what the expected output is of your search?

Comment: I see that you are breaking item in ID, stop and start but you are not using it ... If it's not needed use list comprehension..

Comment: The expected output would be [('227', 1, 227), ('233', 1, 233), ('297', 1, 298), ('316', 1, 316), ('240', 1, 240), ('255', 1, 184)]. The ID number with two values the lowest and the highest of all the start and stop values that have that ID

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that each time you loop over `List`, you reset the value of `List2` with a `List2 = []`. Instead, call that before your for loop:

```
>>> List = [('227', 1, 227), ('233', 1, 233), ('297', 1, 297), ('298', 3, 298), ('316', 1, 316), ('240', 1, 240), ('255', 1, 91), ('255', 92, 184)]
>>> List2 = []
>>> for item in List:
...     ID = item[0]
...     Start = item[1]
...     Stop = item[2]
...     if item not in List2:
...         List2.extend(item)
...     elif item in List2:
...         continue
...     print List2
... 
['227', 1, 227]
['227', 1, 227, '233', 1, 233]
['227', 1, 227, '233', 1, 233, '297', 1, 297]
['227', 1, 227, '233', 1, 233, '297', 1, 297, '298', 3, 298]
['227', 1, 227, '233', 1, 233, '297', 1, 297, '298', 3, 298, '316', 1, 316]
['227', 1, 227, '233', 1, 233, '297', 1, 297, '298', 3, 298, '316', 1, 316, '240', 1, 240]
['227', 1, 227, '233', 1, 233, '297', 1, 297, '298', 3, 298, '316', 1, 316, '240', 1, 240, '255', 1, 91]
['227', 1, 227, '233', 1, 233, '297', 1, 297, '298', 3, 298, '316', 1, 316, '240', 1, 240, '255', 1, 91, '255', 92, 184]
>>> List2
['227', 1, 227, '233', 1, 233, '297', 1, 297, '298', 3, 298, '316', 1, 316, '240', 1, 240, '255', 1, 91, '255', 92, 184]
>>>
```

Basically, what the above code does is *flatten* `List1`. Instead of going through that, I would suggest list comprehension:

```
>>> List1 
[('227', 1, 227), ('233', 1, 233), ('297', 1, 297), ('298', 3, 298), ('316', 1, 316), ('240', 1, 240), ('255', 1, 91), ('255', 92, 184)]
>>> List1 = [('227', 1, 227), ('233', 1, 233), ('297', 1, 297), ('298', 3, 298), ('316', 1, 316), ('240', 1, 240), ('255', 1, 91), ('255', 92, 184)]
>>> List2 = [item for tup in List1 for item in tup]
>>> List2
['227', 1, 227, '233', 1, 233, '297', 1, 297, '298', 3, 298, '316', 1, 316, '240', 1, 240, '255', 1, 91, '255', 92, 184]
>>>
```

Hope this helps!

If you want to find the greatest difference between `item[1]` and `item[2]`, do the following:

```
>>> import math>>> List1 = [('227', 1, 227), ('233', 1, 233), ('297', 1, 297), ('298', 3, 298), ('316', 1, 316), ('240', 1, 240), ('255', 1, 91), ('255', 92, 184)]
>>> List1[[math.fabs(item[2]-item[1]) for item in List1].index(max([math.fabs(item[2]-item[1]) for item in List1]))]
('316', 1, 316)
>>>
```